# How to resolve issue I am getting while creating oracle connection in SSIS project?

Tags: string, oracle, ssis, connection

I am creating one SSIS project where I am supposed to fetch data from my sql server dev environment to my local oracle server.

I tried creating oracle connection with the help of OLEDB DB Source's Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle. When I entered the credentials for the same it is throwing below error:

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

---

My oracle server version is 18c and the oracle client version is 12c (32-bit).Also I have configured the ORACLE_HOME and I ensured that TNS_ADMIN path in environment variables properly point to TNSNames.ora and sqlnet.ora files for 12c client version.

Please find the attach screenshot of the  error:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you have mismatch of 32/64bit?  If SSIS/ODBC is running in 64bit, it is not going know of the existence of a 32bit client

Comment: No SSIS is running on 32-bit only as I have changed the runtime then too this issue.. Please resolve this asap connor.